# How can I concatenate 2 messages in Global Message Service in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, spartacus-storefront

I have a situation in which I would need to concatenate 2 error messages, one is a backend respone and the other one is a localized and translated text.

The piece of code looks like this:

```
   this.globalMessageService.add(
      { key: 'httpHandlers.internalServerError.exception'},
      // errors[0].message,
      GlobalMessageType.MSG_TYPE_ERROR
    );
```

The problem I am having is trying to include the `errors[0].message` string together with the other localized text. Using `+` operator converts the `value` form the existing `key` in a string and the localized text will not be shown.

Any suggestions are welcomed!

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else stumbles across this problem, a solution could be:

```
this.globalMessageService.add(
  {
    key: 'httpHandlers.internalServerError.exception',
    params: { exception: errors[0].message },
  },
  GlobalMessageType.MSG_TYPE_ERROR
);
```

You also need to add `exception` in the translation chunks as follows:

```
internalServerError: {
  exception: 'random text to be translated: {{ exception }}',
},
```